# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop on one user

Tags: 18.04, login

I just recently upgraded to 18.04, leading to one of my user being stuck in a login loop despite correct password. Meanwhile my other user logs in just fine. Any help to remedy this issue would be much helped, as there is valuable data on the one that doesn't work!
I'm quite a novice, so a non-technical explanation would be appreciated!

Edit: I tried to change from gm to lightdm - nothing changed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on may without problems, but from yesterday (february) I have the same problem: only one user being in a login loop (in the login screen). I reinstalled ubuntu using the same /home, and the problem presists. So I think that some configuration file has the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue, and was unable to resolve this. Instead I created a new user and moved the files that I needed over to the new user. Not a small task, but it got me to log in again.